# Matching query doesn't exist in django

Tags: python, django, celery

Here I am getting an error, matching query doesn't exist. It is working in my local machine but when I am running it in docker I am getting this error,

[image]

Comment: it seems, it is not pointing to database b/c either database is not initialized or you are pointing it to wrong db.

Answer (score 0):

If it works locally and fails in docker, it sounds like the dockerized instance isn't pointing to the same db.  The failure implies you are calling

```
UserGameRecords.objects.get(...)
```

When the record doesn't exist.  So my recommendation for you is to make sure that you either initialize the db through some sort of management command or check to make sure that the docker instance is pointed to a database which has the prototypic data.